# Does react element itself has inner text, inner html?

Tags: reactjs

Learning react, i see element examples like this,

```
const element = <Welcome name="Sara" />;
```

Does it support ?

```
const element = <Welcome name="Sara">good day </Welcome>;
```

If so, how to get "good day" while "name" belongs to props ?

Thanks !

Comment: React data-flow is single way and it's designed to do so.

Comment: Whether or not a component accepts *children* depends on how the component is implemented. The creator usually doesn't read props or children data from an element because it's the creator who passes that data in the first place. If you can provide more context about the problem you are trying to solve we could help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of the element is exposed through the `children` prop.

```js
const Welcome = (props) => {
  return <div>
    <p>Hello {props.name}!</p>
    {props.children}
    </div>
};

ReactDOM.render(<Welcome name="Sara">good day </Welcome>, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

React has `children` prop out of the box, which accepts nested content inside Component

```js
function Welcome (props) {
  console.log('props.name', props.name)
  console.log('props.children', props.children)
  return <h1>{props.name} {props.children}</h1>
}

function App () {
  return (
    <div>
      <Welcome name="Sara">good day </Welcome>
      <Welcome name="Sara" />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```